# Angularjs component in head gets rendered into body

Tags: angularjs, components

I'm trying to create a component (here named "**meta-info**") which renders a meta-tag with dynamic information (which is being fetched via Rest-Webservice) into the head-tag.

Problem is: In the processed html the component **won't stay in the head but gets rendered into the body as the first element**, and every script and style tag in the head which follows the component in the code also gets moved into the body. It's like the component automatically opens a body-tag. :-(

Anyone got a tip of how to achieve what I need?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" class="app-basic-an" ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title ng-bind="$ctrl.title"></title>
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge, chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <meta-info></meta-info>

        [...]
    </head>

    <body>
       [...]
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

An AngularJS not allow views to set the page title and insert extra elements into the head.

Try to use additional module `angularjs-viewhead` for it

https://github.com/apparentlymart/angularjs-viewhead

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['viewhead']);
```

```
<meta view-head name="description" content={{metaDescription}}>
```